# Converting QGIS vector layer to single track that can be used in Garmin Basecamp

Tags: qgis, layers, export, gpx

I would like to export a vector layer from QGIS into a GPX file consisting just of a single track. I can export the layer, which in QGIS shows a cycle route, i.e. a single line, in GPX format. I think I need to set GPX_USE_EXTENSIONS to yes. I also set FORCE_GPX_TRACK to yes. The export works fine, but when I open the file in Garmin Basecamp, it shows hundreds of single points and not a single line/track.

How do I export the layer so that it shows just a single track in Basecamp and not hundreds of points?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out yet?